# Creating 1-1 Navigation Property From 1-Many Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working on implementing EF against an existing database that links a training class to it's participants, including the instructor as follows

```
Training
-------------------
ClassId (PK)

TrainingParticipant
-------------------
ParticipantId (PK)
ClassId (FK references Training)
PersonId (FK references Person)
ParticipantRoleId (FK references a role table)
```

The participant table should have 1-10 participants and 1 trainer. (distinguished by their ParticipantRoleId.)  I've started with database first development and generated an edmx and context / models that have mapped the 1-Many relationship between Training and Training Participant; however, the navigation property it generated will bring back a collection of all TrainingParticipant entries.

I am constantly coding queries like this to check for, or get the record for a the single trainer participant like so:

```
var trainer = context.TrainingParticipant.Where(p => p.ParticipantRoleId == 17).FirstOrDefault()

var students = context.TrainingParticipant.Where(p => p.ParticipantRoleId == 2)
```

I'd very much like to have a navigation property that would make accessing these in complex queries and when databinding the models to ui controls more straightforward. Like so:

```
var training = context.Training.Where(t => t.Instructor.Person.FirstName.Contains("John"));
```

Is it possible to create a navigation property like that, preferrably without changing any of the tables?

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a new getter on your EF entity for this new property which returns just returns this value

```
public class MyEntity{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public ICollection<OtherThing> Things {get;set;}
   [NotMapped]
   public OtherThing TheOneRealThing 
   {
       get
       {
           return Things.First();
       }
   }
}
```

Its not a 'real' nav property but for your app it will probably behave exactly as you would expect.

Comment: @user2337991 hmm thats interesting Im not 100% sure how to ignore a property when you include it via a partial with DB first. if the [notmapped] annotation doesnt work im not too sure how you do this. I will have a bit of a think or if anyone else knows im curious